# kubernetes force service to use https

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-apiserver

I want to expose k8s api's using a service. My issue is that the api only respond on port 6443 on https. Any attempt on http return status 400 bad request. How can I "force" the service to user https ?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8s-api
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    label: k8s-api
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80 #Port on which your service is running
    targetPort: 6443
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    name: kube-apiserver-master-node
```

May be this ?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: k8s-api
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    label: k8s-api
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 443 #Port on which your service is running
    targetPort: 6443
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    name: kube-apiserver-master-node
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Nginx ingress by default it does **SSL** **off load** and sends plain **HTTP** in the background.

Changing port **6443** might be helpful if you request direct connecting to the **service**.

If you are using the Nginx ingress make sure it doesn't terminate SSL.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
```

Comment: So the ssl passsthrough attribute and backend protocol ensure that the request will be sent through https to the background. Thanks I'll try it for sure